# New leaves from mango seedling are drying up and dying off but the plant is still growing

Tags: seedlings

I started some mango plants from seed and after a few weeks they're slowly growing. However, now that each plant has a new leaf or two, I've noticed that some of the newer leaves are drying up and falling off before they even get a chance to open up. The main stem is still producing new plant material so the plant isn't dying? Is it that the bigger leaves are sucking up all the nutrients or is it something else?

[image: Dry leaves falling off]

Comment: "Is it that the bigger leaves are sucking up all the nutrients", most likely yes.